# (Solution) - Ubuntu 20.04 - Incorrect Display Settings

Tags: 20.04, display, hdmi

***EDIT: I've successfully managed to correct the issue. More details in the end of the post.***

Whenever I install Ubuntu 18.04 or higher (currently at 20.04), my display settings get messed up. Most notably, **the screen as a whole gets very blurry.**
I took some pics to demonstrate what exactly this problem is. Sorry for the quality, but the prints would not show the issue. Links below:

**Grub examples:**

[image: Should be]

[image: Is]
**Ubuntu Menu examples:**
[image: Should be] 
[image: Is]

From what I found during some searches, it appears to be caused by an incorrect pixel format setup. But I have no idea on how to change it.

***SOLUTION:*** I've followed some simple steps described at a post from [TecDicas](https://tecdicas.com/como-alterar-o-esquema-de-cores-de-ycbcr-para-full-rgb/). All translated below:

**1) Type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` to edit the grub file.** 
**2) Localize the line that says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.** 
**3) Just after `quiet-splash`, add `amdgpu.dc=0` and save the file.** 
**4) Run `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes. Then, reboot the system.**

Done!